# How Firebase SDK works , Rest APIs or Websocket or anything else

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, firebase-analytics

I'm designing analytic platform and planning to develop a mobile SDK to push our custom analytics data into the platform. So I'd like to implement it how Firebased SDK implemented the same thing. I'm just wandering what is the mechanisms used in firebase SDK to achieve this. For example, is it calling APIs to back end or establishing a Websocket connection with back end or any other mechanism to push data into server. Is there any Queue mechanism used in to push multiple events in to server. Some guidance will be really apricated. Initially planning to develop SDK for react-native and will add more frameworks. Also I want to highlight this platform will be developed on AWS environment. Hence would like to know is there any special products related to AWS when its come to capture and store events.

Answer (score 1):

The Google Analytics SDK for Firebase makes HTTP calls to its backend servers, passing [gRPC](https://grpc.io/)-endoded messages back and forth.